# Why are the editing instructions not part of the Stack Overflow FAQ?

Tags: discussion

I included a link in a Stack Overflow question and wanted to edit it. Awhile ago, someone showed me how to make it more like clickable text instead of just a bare URL, but now I can't remember how. I went to the FAQ to find a quick Stack Overflow editing cheat sheet (I'm guessing such a cheat sheet exists), but it's not there. Is there some reason the Stack Overflow FAQ doesn't point to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's the question mark in the upper right hand corner of every textarea (i.e. whenever you post or edit a post). Click it, then click *advanced help*.

[image]

Quick link: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: @waiwai993 thank you for your quick reply and for helping me to overcome my blindness; much appreciated.